# Проблема с кодировкой при выводе из БД

Tags: php, sql, кодировка

Есть таблица в БД. В ней есть значение на кириллице. Допустим, "Мурманск". Всё прекрасно отображается, никаких проблем с кодировкой.

Однако в php при выводе я получаю "нХТНБОУЛ" вместо "Мурманск".

mysql_set_charset("utf8", $db) не помогает.

Версии:

```
php 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.24 / 10.0.33-MariaDB
```

Переменные с кодировками БД:

[image: Переменные с кодировками]

Comment: При каком именно выводе? Куда Вы выводите?

Comment: @anton-shchyrov . да просто на страницу, 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       echo $row[title] 
}

Comment: В заголовке страницы указано, что ее нужно отображать в UTF-8?

Comment: @anton-shchyrov,
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Comment: Всё, разобрался. Отбой :)
Проблема, как я понял, была в том, что данные через putty в БД вносились в некой иной кодировке. Если вносить их через php скрипт в utf-8, то всё нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужна не такая: `mysql_set_charset("utf8", $db)` она устарела на твоей версии, а такая строка: mysql_query('SET NAMES `utf8`// ток в таких скобках `` ютф8');
будет выводить русским шрифтом